# What is a mezrag-holder?

Tags: colonization, language

I stumbled upon this word in one of my anthropology readings. Here's the excerpt.

> The robbers were from a tribe which had not yet submitted to French authority and were in open rebellion against it, and he wanted authorization to go with his *mezrag*-holder, the Marmusha tribal sheikh, to collect the indemnity that, under traditional rules, he had coming to him.

Comment: There should be _some_ kind of language-like tag here. I'm unsure if [tag:language] itself is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been answered with a comment [on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57969/what-is-a-mezrag-holder):

> [mezrag](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fqrsG2jgpkAC&pg=PA12&dq=mezrag&hl=en&sa=X&ei=67c5T_XEL6nN0QWQyoiqCw&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=mezrag&f=false) seems to be a primitive barter/trade-pact custom, so this
>   tribal sheikh is effectively someone acting in a "ceremonial" role
>   ensuring the rules are followed. An honest broker, is my guess. Or
>   maybe he's just the guy that looks after all the loot/danegeld our
>   hero has collected. – [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers)